# recursive directory in php pb

Tags: php, recursion, directory

I don't understand where is  my problem in my code. I try to realise a copy on a directory to another, but the code make a loop

Thanks for your help

Fo example, I want copy the french directory in a new directory called spanish

ps : just information : in the french directory there also are directory and files
        ex there the result:

```
french 
english 
spanish
    ----->french
    ----->english
    ----->spanish
    --------->french
    --------->english
    --------->spanish 
    ------------>french
    ------------>english
    ------------>spanish 
                 ...
```

correct result is :

```
french 
english 
spanish
```

Code:

```
function osc_smartCopy($source, $dest) {
    mkdir($dest, 0755);
    foreach (
    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST) as $item) {
        if ($item->isDir()) {
            mkdir($dest . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $iterator->getSubPathName());
        } else {
            copy($item, $dest . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $iterator->getSubPathName());
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
//default language drectory ==> French
          $lng_default_directory_query = osc_db_query("select directory
                                                       from " . TABLE_LANGUAGES . "
                                                       where code  = '" . DEFAULT_LANGUAGE . "'
                                                      ");
          $lng_default_directory = osc_db_fetch_array($lng_default_directory_query);
          $lng_default_directory = $lng_default_directory['directory'];

// ---------------------------------------------
// -- Copy the new language in admin directory  
// ---------------------------------------------  
//$directory ==>  spanish

          $source = DIR_FS_ADMIN . DIR_WS_LANGUAGES . $lng_default_directory;
          $dest = DIR_FS_ADMIN . DIR_WS_LANGUAGES . $directory;

          print_r($source);
          print_r('<br />'.$dest);

          if (is_dir($source)) {
            osc_smartCopy($source, $dest);
          } else {
            echo 'NO EXIST';
          }
// ---------------------------------------------
// copy the files in the language admin directory
// --------------------------------------------- 
          $source_admin = DIR_FS_ADMIN . DIR_WS_LANGUAGES . $lng_default_directory.'.php';
          $dest_admin = DIR_FS_ADMIN . DIR_WS_LANGUAGES . $directory.'.php';

          if (file_exists($source_admin)) {
            copy($source_admin, $dest_admin);
            chmod($dest_admin, 0644);
          } else {
            osc_redirect(osc_href_link(FILENAME_LANGUAGES));
          }
```

Comment: What is `pb`? problem? Stackoverflow's servers are not so cramped for disk space that people have to use bad abbreviations to save on space usage.